# How to get top "N'th Maximum" value alone from a table in MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume that there is a 'Employee' table with salary as one of the columns.

I want to get the 'Top N'th maximum salary alone from the table.

How this can be fetched easily?

Comment: Top N'th value alone, not all top N value!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 employee.name, employee.salary from (
    SELECT TOP N employee.name, employee.salary
    FROM employee
    ORDER BY employee.salary DESC )
```

This gives the Nth from the top.

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH    (
        SELECT  e.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY employee.salary DESC) AS rn
        FROM    employee
        ) AS q
SELECT  *
FROM    q
WHERE   rn = @n
```

Comment: I was thinking derived table with ROW_NUMBER(), which is about the same here +1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 E.Salary
FROM (SELECT TOP(N) Salary
      FROM Employee
      ORDER BY Salary DESC) E
ORDER BY E.Salary
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP N employee.name, employee.salary
FROM employee
ORDER BY employee.salary DESC
```

?

Comment: Top N'th value alone, not all top N!!

Comment: Then, be clearer on what you want.  'TOP N alone' means -for me- only the TOP N records.
When you just want a single record, then be clearer, and say 'the max salary of the 'TOP N'.

Comment: well, n'th means -- only one record. isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 Salary FROM
(SELECT TOP(N) Salary FROM Employee
ORDER BY Salary DESC) E
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Employees
    ORDER BY Employees.Salary DESC
```